# In vim, how can I map a key to toggle folding over the whole buffer?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

I'd like to map a key to toggle between `foldmethod=indent` and no folding. How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd say <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> (toggle foldenable) does the job. 
No mapping required. (see also `:he folding`)

(*You could also look at <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> and <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>*)

---

Since you want to map it to a single key, proceed as follows:

```
:nnoremap <F10> zi
```

To force the foldmode to `indent` each time (not really recommended for me), you'd need a function:
Add the function to your vimrc[2]:

```
function ForceFoldmethodIndent()
    if &foldenable
        se foldmethod=indent
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <F10> :normal zi^M|call ForceFoldmethodIndent()^M
inoremap <F10> ^O:normal zi^M|call ForceFoldmethodIndent()^M
```

Let me know if that works for you. I appreciate if you accept this answer if it does :)

Cheers

[1] with `behave mswin`
[2] To enter the special keys (e.g. `^O`) in commandline or insertmode use e.g.

- <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> or
- on windows[1] <kbd>Ctrl-Q</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd>

Comment: It's pretty close, but I want to press only one key!

Comment: I tried `map <F10> :set foldmethod=indent<CR>zi`,but it doesn't work the first time it is pressed, unfortunately.

Comment: perhaps map `<F10>` to `zi`? Also expecting too many features in one key is not the vi spirit. Otherwise, the concept failed at the first insertion, which starts with the extra i :)

Comment: Ok, for lack of context and since you still see to have a problem: you probably missed out on the 'normal' command to do `normal zi` in  command mode. I updated the answer with extensive step-by-step and background info. HTH

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I'm sorry but it still doesn't work; in fact, it works worse than my simple mapping! I don't want to set the fold method in my vimrc because I don't want things to be folded by default, only on demand.

Comment: **Fixed version** Ok, the trouble is (apart from my copy-and-paste braindamage) that setting `fdm` also enables folding automatically (duh...). So I updated the answer with a workaround in thanks for the accept :)